# jq: Data denormalisation

Tags: json, jq

I have this json:

```
{
  "headers": ["x", "y", "z"],
  "data": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  "rows": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

and I'd like to end up with this:

```
[{
    "row": "a",
    "header": "x",
    "value": 1
}, {
    "row": "a",
    "header": "y",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "row": "a",
    "header": "z",
    "value": 3
}, {
    "row": "b",
    "header": "x",
    "value": 4
}, {
    "row": "b",
    "header": "y",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "row": "b",
    "header": "z",
    "value": 6
}, {
    "row": "c",
    "header": "x",
    "value": 7
}, {
    "row": "c",
    "header": "y",
    "value": 8
}, {
    "row": "c",
    "header": "z",
    "value": 9
}]
```

How do I do it? I've tinkered with nested `foreach` until my head exploded. jq is so cool but so different. Here's how I would do it in PHP:

```
$jsonString = '{
    "headers": ["x", "y", "z"],
    "data": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "rows": ["a", "b", "c"]
}';
$json = json_decode($jsonString);
$output = [];
$k = 0;
foreach($json->rows as $r) {
    foreach($json->headers as $h) {
        $p = new stdClass();
        $p->row = $r;
        $p->header = $h;
        $p->value = $json->data[$k];
        $output[] = $p;
        $k++;
    }
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
[(.rows|length) as $n
 | (.headers|length) as $hl
 | range(0; $n) as $r
 | range(0; $hl) as $h
 | {row: .rows[$r],
    header: .headers[$h],
    value:  .data[$r * $hl + $h] }
]
```

Comment: Tx. But where would you put the closing bracket?

Comment: Peak, I don't understand your question, I think the solutions works as is and there are no missing brackets.